# Simplifying a for loop to find an item in an array (returned asynchronously) by condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `getItems` that returns an array of objects asynchronously. Each object has a `isOccupied` method that returns a boolean. I wrote a function that takes an index and returns whether index-th item in the array's `isOccupied` is true or false.

```
async itemIsOccupied(index) {
 return getItems().then(items => {
   if (items.length - 1 < index) return false;
   return items[index].isOccupied()
 });
}
```

This just works fine, but the fact that I have to use an async function to fetch the array makes it lengthy. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: It looks fine, except you can use await instead of then to clean up syntax.  Also the bounds check on the items array looks backwards.  The question is `if (index < items.length)`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd clean it up a little like this...

```
async itemIsOccupied(index) {
  const items = await getItems();
  return index < items.length && items[index].isOccupied();
}
```